# sql calculate percentage over grouped data

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table X like this,

```
student ans_status question_id
 1        1          10
 2        -1         10
 3         1         10
 4         0          10
 1        -1         11
 2         1          11
 3         -1          11
 4         -2         11
```

expected o/p is

```
 10   2/3
 11   1/3
```

etc..
Now, i want the data fro each question 10 like, 
number of 1's/(total of 1's and -1's for each question)
I have tried this,

```
select (select count(student_id) from X
        where question_id=10 and ans_status=1) / count(student_id)
from X
where question_id=10
group by ans_status
having ans_status in(1,-1).
```

i can do it in a nested query, by again selecting and grouping according to the status condition, but is there any way better to do this? 
please note i want this for all questions in the table

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result? (Table format.)

Comment: Put regular column conditions in the WHERE clause. The HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do:

```
select question_id,
       avg(ans_status = 1)
from X
where ans_status in (1, -1)
group by question_id;
```

This uses the MySQL feature that a boolean expression is treated as an integer in a numeric context.  "True" is `1` and "false" is `0`, so the average turns out to be the percentage that are true.

If you want the values independently:

```
select question_id,
       sum(ans_status = 1), count(*)
from X
where ans_status in (1, -1)
group by question_id;
```

Comment: It works, but can you explain, what does avg(ans_status=1) do?

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` for taking count of each `question_id` for getting count of `answer_id` is 1 or -1.

**Query**

```
select t.`question_id`,
t.`count_1` / t.`total_count` as `new_col` from(
    select `question_id`,
    sum(case `ans_status` when 1 then 1 when -1 then 1 else 0 end) as `count_1`,
    count(*) as `total_count`
    from `your_table_name`
    group by `question_id`
)t;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://rextester.com/FUY31278)**

Comment: I am sorry i forgot to add, there are other states for ans_status, like -2 etc, but i am only interested in 1 and -1, thats why i was using group by over that

Comment: use CONCAT_WS('/', t.`count_1`, t.`total_count`) as `new_col` to produce percentage column as x/y

Comment: @Bhargav : I have updated my answer. Please check it .

Comment: This wont work, because count(*) gives 4(3 1's and 1 0) for question 10, where as i want only 3.